# Stored procedure not updating table as expected

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am running a stored procedure on my MySQL database and it says it runs fine, no errors come back, but when I check the table it's supposed to have updated nothing has changed.

When I manually run each individual part of the procedure it works fine, I get back what I expect. All the selects run fine.

I'm fairly new in dealing with stored procedures so I'm not sure how to debug this. Can I get it to output the different stages it's at so I can make sure it gets to the update query? Can I check the results of the queries it's running?

I googled the issue but I didn't find anything helpful. The manual only had information on how to set the procedure up, not how to debug it when it wasn't working (unless I missed something).

This is my whole procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE QuestionStatistics(IN quizId INT(11))
BEGIN
  DECLARE bDone INT;
  DECLARE qqId INT;
  DECLARE totalAnswers INT;
  DECLARE totalCorrect INT;
  DECLARE totalValue INT;
  DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR  SELECT qqId FROM quizQuestions WHERE qqQuizId = quizId;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET bDone = 1;
  OPEN curs;

  SET bDone = 0;
  REPEAT
    FETCH curs INTO qqId;

    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM quizAnswers 
    WHERE qaQuizQuestionId = qqId 
    AND qaIsMarked = 1 
    INTO totalAnswers;

    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM quizAnswers 
    WHERE qaQuizQuestionId = qqId 
    AND qaIsCorrect = 1 
    INTO totalCorrect;

    SELECT SUM(qaValue)
    FROM quizAnswers 
    WHERE qaQuizQuestionId = qqId 
    AND qaIsMarked = 1 
    INTO totalValue;

    UPDATE quizQuestions
    SET qqAveragePoints = ROUND(totalValue / totalAnswers, 2),
    qqPercentageCorrect = ROUND(100 * totalCorrect / totalAnswers)
    WHERE qqId = qqId;
  UNTIL bDone END REPEAT;

  CLOSE curs;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

I'd appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction on how to debug this, or if they could spot the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug your procedure using debugger feature in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/) (try trial version).

I suggest you to optimize your queries, e.g. use one SELECT query instead of three ones -

```
SELECT
  COUNT(IF(qaIsMarked = 1, 1, NULL)),
  COUNT(IF(qaIsCorrect = 1 , 1, NULL)),
  SUM(IF(qaIsMarked = 1, qaValue, 0)
  INTO totalAnswers, totalCorrect, totalValue
FROM
  quizAnswers 
WHERE
  qaQuizQuestionId = qqId;
```

To avoid errors - do not use the same names for parameters, variables and object names like columns.

Also, try to avoid using cursors at all, write one complex UPDATE query.